# What is the difference between MainWindows show() and showAll() method in GtkD?

Tags: user-interface, d, gtkd

Here is my test:

```
import gtk.Main;
import gtk.MainWindow;
import gtk.Label;

void main(string[] args)
{
    Main.init(args);
    auto window = new MainWindow("My Window");
    window.add(new Label("Label1"));
    window.show();
    Main.run();
}
```

When I replace `Main.show()` with `Main.showAll()` it works as expected, however I can't find any documentation for either function here: http://api.gtkd.org/src/gtk/MainWindow.html What is the difference between these two methods and where can I find documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These links from official GTK+ documentation should help: [`gtk_widget_show`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.show.html), [`gtk_widget_show_all`](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/method.Widget.show_all.html). In short, `show` shows only the widget it is called on, and `show_all`, being applied to a container, shows all widgets in this container recursively.

GtkD has very poor and nearly impossible to use API docs, though this seems to be a problem not of GtkD but of D tools. The methods you are referring to are defined on `GtkWidget` class, but unfortunately the [page about `gtk.Widget`](http://api.gtkd.org/src/gtk/Widget.html) is empty (mostly).